# Record last 24 hours of cpu usage data and run query on that in Prometheus monitoring

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I am using Prometheus monitoring to monitor couple of nodes(virtual machines).
I am trying to write a alert rule i.e **if avg of all cpu cores usage in the last 24 hours is less than a threshold value then fire the alert for the same.**.
(basically if a virtual machine has been idle all along in the last 24 hours then fire alert).

For this i want to create a record rule to record the data for last 24 hours and then i want to create an alert to analyse the last 24 hours data and fire alert if the query is true).

what should be the rules yaml file for that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check the next page:

https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/

You have some basic alerts for node-exporter (CPU, RAM, disk, network, systemd...):

https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/rules#host-and-hardware

Enjoy!